# Android studio - deploy apk with pre-set sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-studio

My app uses sharedpreferences for storing login & options details.

I want to deploy my application to my device or to the AndroidStudio VM with the required sharedpreferences values already set in place so that I do not have to re-enter them when I clear the installed app's data or remove the app altogether. For the sake of convenience and also because storing hardcoded credentials is dangerous.

Is it possible to do this for my development builds ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating app.properties file in assets folder and store default values here. Then just use it for debug build.

```
val inputStream = assets.open("app.properties")
Properties().load(inputStream)
val defaultPassword = Properties().getProperty("password")
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(KEY, defaultPassword).apply()
}
```

in app.propersties:

```
password=<my_password>
```

Of course you must put this file in .gitignore.